# Como ativar uma div com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou com o seguinte problema tenho uma `<div>` oculta em cima do campo login:

```
<div id="MostraLegenda" class ="legenda" style ="display: none">
    <p>Login do Usuario</p>
</div>
```

Ela está com o `display: none`, quero utilizar o evento `onmouseover` e coloca-la como `display: block`.

JS:

```
function mostrarLegenda()
{
    var div;
    div = document.getElementById("MostraLegenda");
    div.setAttribute.apply("style", "display:block");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conseguir fazer com que o elemento apareça, utilize o seguinte código para retornar a propriedade **style** deste objeto que lhe dará acesso ao CSS do elemento.

Veja o exemplo abaixo utilizando sua própia função:

```
function mostrarLegenda() {
    document.getElementById("MostraLegenda").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Você também pode utilizar uma forma automatizada de aparecer/desaparecer:

```
function mostrarLegenda() {
    var div = document.getElementById("MostraLegenda");

    if (div.style.display == 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para alterar o estilo de um elemento você pode acessar as propriedades usando `elemento.style.[propriedade]`

```
function mostrarLegenda()
{
    var div;
    var estilo;
    div = document.getElementById("MostraLegenda");
    estilo = div.style.display;
    div.style.display = (estilo == 'none') ? 'none' : 'block';

    return true;
}
```

Comment: deu certo, só mais uma questão, eu consigo comparar com um if assim if(div.style.display == 'none'){

Comment: Consegue sim, só checar `if( elemento.style.display == 'none' //ou 'block')`